# Recursively apply grep based on values from multiple columns

Tags: r

I want to `grep` values from multiple columns and then assign a priority in case there is a conflict. I was able to write a workable code, but it's too repetitive in that I am not really fully utilizing the power of vectorized operation in R. I am looking for a solution with `lapply` , `sapply` etc.

I tried dabbling around with `lapply` but got stuck.

**Here are my data:**

```
dput(DF)
structure(list(S6 = c("FED AIR FORCE", "FED AIR FORCE", "FED AIR FORCE", 
"FED MARINES", "FED MARINES", "FED MARINES", "FED NAVY", "FED NAVY", 
"FED NAVY", "FED NAVY", "FEDERAL", "STATE", "STATE"), S.Name = c("MARINE", 
"ARMY", "AIR FORCE", "MARINE", "ARMY", "AIR FORCE", "MARINE", 
"ARMY", "AIR FORCE", "NAVY", "NAVY", "AIR FORCE", "FEDERAL"), 
    Dept = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), Number = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 
    10, 11, 12, 12)), .Names = c("S6", "S.Name", "Dept", "Number"
), row.names = c(NA, 13L), class = "data.frame")
```

**Here's my code that's working:**

```
Divisions<-c("Air Force", "Army", "Navy", "Marine")
DF[grep("AIR FORCE",DF$S.Name,ignore.case = TRUE),"Dept"]<-"Air Force"
DF[grep("Army",DF$S.Name,ignore.case = TRUE),"Dept"]<-"Army"
DF[grep("Navy",DF$S.Name,ignore.case = TRUE),"Dept"]<-"Navy"
DF[grep("Marine",DF$S.Name,ignore.case = TRUE),"Dept"]<-"Marine"

DF[grep("AIR FORCE",DF$S6,ignore.case = TRUE),"Dept"]<-"Air Force"
DF[grep("Army",DF$S6,ignore.case = TRUE),"Dept"]<-"Army"
DF[grep("Navy",DF$S6,ignore.case = TRUE),"Dept"]<-"Navy"
DF[grep("Marine",DF$S6,ignore.case = TRUE),"Dept"]<-"Marine"
```

Commentary: First I read `S.Name`, if there is a match, I write the match. Then, I read `S6`, if there is a match, I overwrite it. So, `S6` has a priority over `S.Name`.

**Expected Output after running above operations:**

```
dput(DF)
structure(list(S6 = c("FED AIR FORCE", "FED AIR FORCE", "FED AIR FORCE", 
"FED MARINES", "FED MARINES", "FED MARINES", "FED NAVY", "FED NAVY", 
"FED NAVY", "FED NAVY", "FEDERAL", "STATE", "STATE"), S.Name = c("MARINE", 
"ARMY", "AIR FORCE", "MARINE", "ARMY", "AIR FORCE", "MARINE", 
"ARMY", "AIR FORCE", "NAVY", "NAVY", "AIR FORCE", "FEDERAL"), 
    Dept = c("Air Force", "Air Force", "Air Force", "Marine", 
    "Marine", "Marine", "Navy", "Navy", "Navy", "Navy", "Navy", 
    "Air Force", NA), Number = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 
    11, 12, 12)), .Names = c("S6", "S.Name", "Dept", "Number"
), row.names = c(NA, 13L), class = "data.frame")
```

I want to be able to vectorize this...i.e. use `lapply`

---

Here's what I tried with `lapply`:

```
l<-lapply(Divisions,function (x) {sort(unique(append(grep(x,DF$S.Name,ignore.case = TRUE),grep(x,DF$S6,ignore.case = TRUE))))})
```

Unfortunately, I don't know how to assign priority and feed the values back to the data frame.
I'd appreciate any thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `str_extract` to extract the specific words in 'S6' column from 'Divisions' `vector` by `paste`ing the the elements together, then use `gsub` to change it to camel case by matching a capital letter after a word boundary (`\\b`) followed by one or more capital letters (`([A-Z]+)`), captured both as a group, and in the replacement, we use the backreference of the first (`\\1`) followed by specifying lower case (`\\L`) for the second backreference (`\\2`)

```
library(stringr)
DF$Dept <- gsub("(\\b[A-Z])([A-Z]+)", "\\1\\L\\2", str_extract(DF$S6, 
         paste(toupper(Divisions), collapse="|")), perl = TRUE)
DF$Dept
#[1] "Air Force" "Air Force" "Air Force" "Marine"    "Marine"    "Marine"    "Navy"      "Navy"      "Navy"      "Navy"      NA         
#[12] NA          NA
```

If there are `NA` elements in 'Dept', then change it by applying the same method in 'S.Name'

```
i1 <- is.na(DF$Dept)
DF$Dept[i1] <- gsub("(\\b[A-Z])([A-Z]+)", "\\1\\L\\2", 
     str_extract(DF$S.Name[i1],  paste(toupper(Divisions), collapse="|")), perl = TRUE)
DF$Dept
#[1] "Air Force" "Air Force" "Air Force" "Marine"    "Marine"    "Marine"    "Navy"      "Navy"      "Navy"      "Navy"      "Navy"     
#[12] "Air Force" NA
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you please explain the steps? Also, I find myself really struggling with regular expressions. It would have taken one day for me to come up with what you have above. Do you have any tips on how I can improve my skills with regex?

Comment: @watchtower I updated the post.  Hope it helps.  You can also check http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html

Comment: Thanks again for your help. Do you think we could do the same using `lapply` i.e. without using regex?

Comment: @watchtower You can loop over the `Divisions` and then assign it, but I would use a `for` loop for assignment.

Comment: Thanks. I wrote this: `l<-lapply(Divisions,function (x) {sort(unique(append(grep(x,DF$S.Name,ignore.case = TRUE),grep(x,DF$S6,ignore.case = TRUE))))})` but I don't know how to substitute values back into the data.frame and assign priority. Any help would be greatly appreciated.